# Interesting usage of "considered"

Tags: word-usage

A recent article on BBC online had the following phrase describing a Bedouin subject in an interview" ... he speaks considered English slowly ..."

Is this an acceptable usage of "considered" in this sense?

Comment: Yes.  It means the speaker is thinking and reflecting about what they are about to say in English very carefully before or as they are saying it.  Common among those who are speaking a language that is not native to them.

Comment: @JohnH And desirable among those who are speaking their native language!

Comment: @Ishmael...carefully weighed ....

Comment: From _Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary_ (2003): "**considered** *adj* (ca. 1677) **1 :** matured by extended deliberative thought {a _considered_ opinion} **2 :** viewed with respect or esteem." The intended sense of _considered_ in your example is the first one that MW identifies, I think.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it does.

When used as an adjective, "Considered" means:

> 1. Thought about or decided upon with care: a considered opinion.
> 2. Regarded with respect or esteem: a highly considered person.

[[Dictionary.Com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/considered)]

The particular usage you are asking about fits into the first definition.